# Funcion javascript con parametros no responde

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tengo una pagina aspx con esta carousel de imagenes que son botones al mismo tiempo:

```
        <div id="carousel">
          <figure><asp:ImageButton id="puzzle1" ImageUrl="~/images/puzzle1.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive image" runat="server" OnClientClick="showModel('uno'); return false"/></figure>
          <figure><asp:ImageButton id="puzzle2" ImageUrl="~/images/puzzle2.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive image" runat="server" OnClientClick="showModel('dos'); return false"/></figure>
          <figure><asp:ImageButton id="puzzle3" ImageUrl="~/images/puzzle3.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive image" runat="server" OnClientClick="showModel('tres'); return false"/></figure>
          <figure><asp:ImageButton id="puzzle4" ImageUrl="~/images/puzzle4.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive image" runat="server" OnClientClick="showModel('cuatro'); return false"/></figure>
          <figure><asp:ImageButton id="puzzle5" ImageUrl="~/images/puzzle5.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive image" runat="server" OnClientClick="showModel('cinco'); return false"/></figure>
          <figure><asp:ImageButton id="puzzle6" ImageUrl="~/images/puzzle6.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive image" OnClick="linkButton6_Click" runat="server"/></figure>
        </div>
```

Cada uno de estos botones tiene una funcion `OnClientClick="showModel(PARAMETRO);`

Mas abajo, detro del cuerpo `HTML` Tengo esa misma funcion declarada de la siguente forma:

```
    <script>
    function showModel(variable) {
        if (variable == "uno") {
            '<%Session["tipoPuzzle"] = "uno"; %>';
        }
        if (variable == "dos") {
            '<%Session["tipoPuzzle"] = "dos"; %>';
        }
        if (variable == "tres") {
            '<%Session["tipoPuzzle"] = "tres"; %>';
        }
        if (variable == "cuatro") {
            '<%Session["tipoPuzzle"] = "cuatro"; %>';
        }
        if (variable == "cinco") {
            '<%Session["tipoPuzzle"] = "cinco"; %>';
        }
        $('.modal').modal();
    }

</script>
```

El trabajo principal de esta funcion es:

**En base al clic que haga el usuario, llenar una variable de session y abrir otra pagina (dinamica) la cual se construye en base a esa variable de session.**

El problema es que siempre me toca el parametro 'cinco' y nada mas. Haga el clic donde haga, solo viaja el parametro 'cinco'.

Quiero pedirles ayuda con ese problema y si ven alguna forma de optimizar la funcion, sus consejos son bienvenidos.

Answer (score 0):

¿no puedes hacer sencillamente:

```
function showModel(variable) {
    '<%Session["tipoPuzzle"] = '+variable+'; %>';
    $('.modal').modal();
}
```

Y aun podrias hacerlo mas sencillo si usas siempre la función

```
showModel()
```

y haces

```
function showModel() {
    '<%Session["tipoPuzzle"] = '+$(this).attr("id")+'; %>';
    $('.modal').modal();
}
```

poniendo como ids "uno", "dos", etc.

Comment: Lamentablemente no, ya lo probe y en este caso, a la otra pagina (dentro de la variable de session) llega **'+variable+'**. Tal cual literalmente el nombre de la variable en vez de contenido

Comment: Perdon, ahora que lo veo bien creo que estas mezclando lenguajes y asp no interpreta los if/else,

Comment: Como que no, deberia interpretar. Bah nunca tuve ese problema, siempre me interpretaba bien javascript antes.

Comment: @OrenDiaz has hecho uso del else if?

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev probe con switch, else if no. El switch tampoco me funciono. O sea, entra en el case del switch, agarra el parametro bien, pero despues por alguna razon lo pierde y se reemplaza por el parametro "cinco"